# Value sorting from text file

Tags: vb.net

i have text file as following format

> A00 B45 C67
>   A00 B87 C89
>   A00 B35 C65
>   A00 B23 C87

HOW TO FIND MINIMUM , MAXIMUM VALUE OF B AND C

Comment: Please read [Ask] and also take the [Tour].

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it would be like this:

```
Dim str As String =
"A00 B45 C67
A00 B87 C89
A00 B35 C65
A00 B23 C87"

Dim lines As String() = 
    str.Split({ControlChars.CrLf}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

Dim listB As New List(Of Integer)
listB.AddRange(From line As String In lines Select CInt(line.Split()(1).Remove(0, 1)))
listB.Sort()

Dim listC As New List(Of Integer)
listC.AddRange(From line As String In lines Select CInt(line.Split()(2).Remove(0, 1)))
listC.Sort()

Dim minB As Integer = listB.First()
Dim maxB As Integer = listB.Last()

Dim minC As Integer = listC.First()
Dim maxC As Integer = listC.Last()
```